# How to send whatsapp messages when data is inserted into database using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, twilio-api

I want to send a Whatsapp number to the number inserted into the sqlite. I am new to python and Django.

```
class Invoice (models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    buyer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    buyer_phone_number = models.CharField(
        validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

        from_whatsapp_number = 'whatsapp:+14155238886'

        to_whatsapp_number = 'whatsapp:%d' % buyer_phone_number

        client.messages.create(body='Invoice created',
                               from_=from_whatsapp_number,
                               to=to_whatsapp_number)

        super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

It seems it cannot read the variable. This is the error message: 'buyer_phone_number' is not defined

Comment: Why does "it seem" that? What problem are you having? What variable can't it read? What error do you get?

Comment: @DanielRoseman This is the error message: 'buyer_phone_number' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

`buyer_phone_number` is an instance attribute. In Python you must always refer to these via the instance itself, ie `self`.

```
   to_whatsapp_number = 'whatsapp:%d' % self.buyer_phone_number
```